# can i install kubuntu desktop on ubuntu with windows 8 dual boot?

Tags: grub2, kde

I have set up dual boot w8 and ubuntu 13.04 and i'd like to try kde.
What steps should i take to install it and also i would like to know if i'll be able to choose kde from login menu (currently i have unity and gnome)

Also, can this screw up grub2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just type `sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop` in the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

To install KDE, just install the [kubuntu-dekstop [image: Install kubuntu-dekstop]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/kubuntu-dekstop) package with your favourite package manager. Then you will be able to select a different "session" in the login screen.

Some facts that will make it more clear to you.

- KDE is just a desktop environment. A set of packages, some applications, etc. It will install next to any other desktop environment you have installed (e.g. Unity). Kubuntu is just Ubuntu without Unity (by default), but that comes with KDE preselected. Installing Ubuntu, then installing KDE (kubuntu metapackages) and uninstalling Unity (not required) will make it Kubuntu effectively.
- Ubuntu in dual boot or not, it's just Ubuntu. You can install any package in that installation, it really does not matter if there's a Windows installation on another partition/disk somewhere.
- Grub is a bootloader. This is involved in the boot process to load the kernel. This is a few stages before anything of a desktop environment is loaded. So no, it won't affect anything of Grub.

Comment: Oh, great then... Want to try kde cause i can't get used to gnome and unity somehow...